# How configure include path and use standard library with gcc compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc

I know this topic was few times there, but I can't get satisfactory answer.

```
C:\Users\Krzysiek>gcc test.c
test.c:3:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This is what I try to do

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Simple program with "include"

I've heard of LIBRARY_PATH. So I've setted that. Still this same error I have.

Comment: In what way did you not get a satisfactory answer? The answer is simple and has been given many, many times.

Comment: I know this was foolish ask and solution was so simple. I think I'm just stupid. :) Sorry for this wording "I can't get satisfactory answer.". I mean I can't find answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC provides wrappers around calling its various compilers.

- You are using `gcc`, which is for C (and consequently will not include or link the C++ standard library; the compiler *would* go on to complain about the rest of your code, too, since it's not valid C);
- Use `g++`, which is for C++.

Also try to use a conventional extension for C++ source files, which is `.cc`, `.cxx` or `.cpp`.

Comment: Note that the OP's file's extension is `.c`, i.e. C not C++.

Answer (score 2):

Use `g++` instead: it will link to the c++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `gcc` command, `gcc` looks at the file extension to decide which language to use to compile. As you used a `.c` file, `gcc` will switch by default to C.

```
# Use the C compiler
gcc test.c

# Use the C++ compiler
gcc test.cpp
```

To choose a different language, you can use the `-x` option:

```
# Use the C++ compiler even if the extension is .c
gcc -xc++ test.c
```

Another method of using the C++ compiler is to use `g++` in the command line. This is the preferred way, as it links with the correct libraries.

```
# Use the C++ compiler
g++ test.c
```